# How do I use the chain rule to prove this couple of differentiations?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider the following from van den Ban’s *Lie Groups* (webspace.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/lie2019/lie2010.pdf), pp. 18-20:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

1. **I am trying to prove the last equation**

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\ad}{ad} \DeclareMathOperator{\Ad}{Ad} \ad
(X)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\Ad
(\exp(tX))  \tag{*}$$

**How do I use the chain rule to prove it?**

My solution is the following but I don’t think I am using the chain rule (or I maybe I am using without being aware of it):

I write $X$ as the derivative at $t=0$ of a curve $\gamma$ living in $G$, that would be the exponential map $\exp(tX)$:

$$\ad
(X)=T_e(\Ad
)(X)=T_e(\Ad
) \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\gamma(t).$$

Now I use the definition of the action of a tangent map (differential) on a vector of the tangent space, meaning that it maps velocities into velocities (tangent vectors into tangent vectors). If $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\alpha(t)$ is a tangent vector this translates into $T_e(f)\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\alpha(t)= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(f(\alpha(t))$, with $f$ some smooth function. In my problem:

$$ \ad(X)=T_e(\Ad)(X)=T_e(\Ad) \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\gamma(t)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \Ad
(\exp(tX)).$$

**Is this a correct procedure? Is using the chain rule an alternative approach? How do I use it then?**

2. **If this is correct, where is that $T_0(\exp)$ coming out from in the following differentiation (p.20 in the notes), for $Z \in T_eG$:**

$$\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0}\Ad(\exp(sZ))Z = \ad(Z)T_0(\exp)Z ?$$

I would just substitute equation $(*)$ like this:

$$ \left. \frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} \Ad(\exp(sZ))Z= \ad(Z)Z \tag{**}$$

and the result is the same because actually $T_0(\exp)$ can be shown to be the identity map, but still what is going on here?

I am not very familiar with differential geometry manipulations so please be detailed in your use of the chain rule.

---

**Edit** Let me do (2) in detail as suggested using the chain rule:
calling $\alpha: s \mapsto \alpha(s)=sZ$

$$\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0} Ad(\exp(sZ)))Z = T_0 Ad(exp(\alpha(s)))Z = T_0 (Ad \circ \exp \circ \alpha(s) Z) $$
$$= T_{exp(\alpha(0))}Ad\circ T_{\alpha(0)}\exp\circ T_{0}\alpha(s) Z $$
$$= T_{e}Ad \circ T_{0} \exp \circ T_{0}\alpha(s) Z =ad \circ T_{0} \exp \circ Z Z$$ $$=ad(Z)Z$$  Makes sense? However since $Z \in T_e G $ and $\alpha(s) $ is the curve whose derivative at $0$ is $Z$, shouldn't I have $\alpha(0)=e$? , instead of that I am using $\alpha(0)=0Z=0 $  And something else how's that Z at the end of the expression is not affected by anything the whole time?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in 1. and in 2. it seems a more explicit composition of functions is being considered.

For $X\in T_eG$, the adjoint operator $\text{ad}_X$ is defined as the derivative of the function $\mathbb{R}\to \text{GL}(T_eG)$, $t\mapsto \text{Ad}(\exp(tX))$ evaluated at $t=0$. Writing this function out explicitly as a composition we have

[image]

(Here $f:(A,a)\to(B,b)$ means $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ and $f(a)=b$.)

You are using the chain rule with this composition in the last equality in the chain

> $$\text{ad}(X)=T_e(\text{Ad})(X)=T_e(\text{Ad}) \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\gamma(t)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \text{Ad}(\exp(tX))$$

On the other hand (for 2.) one can also consider the composition as

[image]

in which case there would be a factor of $T_0(\exp)$, which like you said is identity and can be ignored. Note that the derivative of the first map at $0$ is $X$.

---

**Added:** As per request, here is a comparison of the tangent functor notation and the Leibniz notation:

$$\left.\dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \gamma(t) = \left.\dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \exp(\bullet X) = T_0 \exp(\bullet X) \left( \left.\dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\right) = T_0 \gamma \left( \left.\dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\right).$$

Here in the last expression $\left.\dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\in T_0\mathbb{R}$ stands for the basis vector normalized by way of the standard Riemannian (Euclidean) metric of $\mathbb{R}$. The functorial chain rule does not see this choice of an element in $T_0\mathbb{R}$, hence would give the equality of two linear operators:

$$T_0 [\text{Ad}(\exp(\bullet X))] = T_e \text{Ad} \circ T_0\exp(\bullet X): \mathbb{R}\cong T_0\mathbb{R}\to T_I (\text{GL}(T_e G))\cong \text{End}(T_e G).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, If I understood well, what I did in (1) is actually the chain rule backwards?  The chain rule for differentials (tangent maps) I know is $T_p(f \circ g)=T_{g(p)}f\circ T_pg$, but at the end of my chain in (1) I have $d/dt|_{t=0}$. I am suspecting this can be written as a differential, can you show how?

Comment: @mathlover I've added some related details; I hope they will be useful.

Comment: So $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\gamma(t)= T_0 \gamma(t)$ ?

Comment: @mathlover Yes modulo some formalisms.

Comment: However in your added chain you end up with $T_e\gamma(t)$ ($e$ instead of $0$) and with a basis vector that I am not getting

Comment: @mathlover That's a typo, sorry.

Comment: See my edit, I tried to do (2) using your suggestion, makes sense? But there is a problem with the application point as stated

Comment: @mathlover It seems about right; your $\alpha$ is a curve taking values in $T_eG$, and this latter being a linear space there is a canonical isomorphism $T_eG\cong T_0 T_eG$.

Comment: So $ \alpha(0)= e$  is wrong?  The correct one is $\alpha(0)=0$? with $0$ the $0$ vector in $T_eG$? See also the last part of the question :how's that Z at the end of the expression is not affected by anything the whole time?

Comment: @mathlover Yes, yes, yes; it's not clear to me which $Z$ you are talking about but the first $Z$ in $\text{ad}_Z(Z)$ ought to be left alone as you are trying to associate an operator (the adjoint) to it, and the second $Z$ ought to be left alone because the adjoint operator ought to take inputs purely from $T_eG$.